# Moment.js format and Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

moment.js format is working perfectly in localhost and converted ISO time to local time correctly. Unfortunately, in Google Cloud App Engine, it formatted perfectly but hasn't converted ISO time to local time. Why?

node.js application using an express framework and Pug template engine.

Here is my code:

```
var isoTime ="2018-01-09T09:16:30.057Z";
console.log(moment(isoTime).format('HH:mm'));
output in local host 11:16 
output in google cloud app engine 09.16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the timedate obtained by `moment()` to local timezone of your choice using moment().utcOffset(x):

```
var isoTime ="2018-01-09T09:16:30.057Z"; 
console.log(moment(isoTime).utcOffset(2).format('HH:mm'))
// will print 11:16 in any environment
```

Comment: Thanks! its work by using utcOffset but I tried to use local() it doesn't work in google cloud app engine. 
moment(isoTime).local().format('HH:mm'). output same 9:16

Comment: Local time on GAE is most likely UTC, as Abhyudit suggest above, so it's expected behavior on GAE. What end goal are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Moment uses system time as local time. Your localhost (your computer) must be using the local time hence the difference. But Google Cloud app engine is configured to use UTC as system time. Hence for it, UTC and local are the same.